# Convert custom array object to string array

Tags: c#

I'm trying to convert an object array of my class to a string array.

In this example I have two classes. In one of my classes I want to creat two variables, objects of the other class. On variable will be a array and the other a "regular" variable.

Two classes name. ShowResult and Game.

In the Game class I write:

```
private ShowResult[] _showResults;
private ShowResult _showResult;
```

In my properties in my Game class I try to convert this two variables to string array and string:

```
    public string[] ShowResults
    {
        get { return _showResults.ToString().ToArray(); }
        set { _showResults.ToString().ToArray() = value; }
    }

    public string ShowResult
    {
        get { return _showResult.ToString(); }
        set { _showResult = value; }
    }
```

This doesn't work. I really want my custom object to be converted to string array and to string. But I get an error.. I know I can, but I don't know just how..

If anyone has any suggestion I would be greatful. OBS, this is just an example. But still I don't get why it wont work..?

By the way, sorry for my bad english. ;)

Best regards

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w86s7x04(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Do you have code that parses a string into an instance of your `ShowResult`? You will need to use that in your property setter.

Comment: Good point Hans Kesting. No I don't. Do you have any ideas how to parse a string array to my ShowResult array? Hmm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
_showResults.Select(a => a.ToString()).ToArray()
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the nature of your code (i.e. strings appear to map directly to `ShowResults` instances), you might want to consider implementing `implicit` operators:

```
ShowResults s = "hello";
string ss = s;
Console.WriteLine(ss); // "hello"



class ShowResults
{
    public string SomeProp
    {
        get; private set;
    }
    public static implicit operator ShowResults(string s)
    {
        //this is where you'd parse your string
        //to form a valid ShowResults
        return new ShowResults{SomeProp = s};
    }
    public static implicit operator string(ShowResults s)
    {
        return s.SomeProp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Very intresting solution! Thank you for your time. :)